# Create a mobile app that listens to incoming phone call events

Tags: iphone, android, blackberry, mobile, cross-platform

As the title suggests, I would like to create a mobile app that runs in the background and catches "incoming call" events. Moreover I would like to use a [Cross-Platform Development Tool](http://mashable.com/2010/08/11/cross-platform-mobile-development-tools/) to do this.

I looked at three tools: [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com/), [Rhomobile](http://rhomobile.com/) and [Appcelerator](http://www.appcelerator.com/). But I couldn't find any documentation or examples that suggest they support such events.

It seems like the iPhone (correct me if I'm wrong) does not support this but [Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html) and [Blackberry](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/blackberry/api/phone/PhoneListener.html) do.

Did I miss something when I looked at the above mentioned tools and platforms?
Are there any other well established Cross-Platform Mobile Tools that could solve my problem?
Keeping the cross-platform support in mind, what approach would you follow to develop such an app?

Answer (score 3):

On the iPhone, there's nothing you can do to "catch" or even register incoming calls. The only thing you could do is create an app that protocols the time at which it has been sent to the background or became inactive, because you'r appdelegate will be notified - but that will happen on many occasions, not only when a phone call is received. It won't work while the app is in the background (on multitasking enabled devices) alltogether. So, an app like this would be totally useless...

Sorry, no help there!