# How do I capture an "incoming call" instead of being booted to the background?

Tags: ios, events, handler, telephony

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create a mobile app that listens to incoming phone call events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3573859/create-a-mobile-app-that-listens-to-incoming-phone-call-events)

I would like to be able to capture an 'incoming call' event in my application. I'd like to execute a task based on the incoming call details before handing the call over to the defaults call application.

From my research online, I understand that the application's *applicationWillResignActive* method is called when an incoming call occurs. However this puts the application in the background and I lose the fore-ground user interaction capability that I need. In the background, the best case scenario is to send a notification to the foreground.

Is there a way to attach an event handler deeper into the iOS framework to capture the event before the Apple's default call application. I do not need the application running *during* the call.

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 2):

The framwork has no (public) hooks for phone calls because they don't want apps to interfere with the behavior of iOS.

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic example of a feature which fails the "what if everyone did this" test. Ergo, it's not going to be something that is allowed by the framework.

See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/06/07/426294.aspx